# Added Play Store test credentials In App Access after the production rollout

Tags: android, google-play

When I was uploading the new build on the google play store in the production track, I forgot to add test credentials in the App Access section. So after the gap of one day (from production rollout ), I updated the test account credentials in the App Access section, so is it necessary for me to again rollout on the production track, or the google bot will pick my test account?

Thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

So update is we can add test account after rolling out on production track even after the delay of one day, this is what happend to me and build got approved.